# createPeriodicWave from an array of sample values

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I have a curve -- say, a sine curve -- that is sampled at uniform intervals into a Float32Array, called *samples*. The curve is sampled by *value*. If *samples* (with some rounding) was put on the screen, we would get something like the following:

```
 1.0 |    x           x
 0.5 |  x   x       x   x
 0.0 | x     x     x     x     x
-0.5 |        x   x       x   x
-1.0 |          x           x
```

And the contents of the *samples* array is something along these numbers:

```
0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, -0.5, -1, -0.5, 0, ...
```

As you can see, the curve is represented by the *value* of the curve at each given sample. I would like to create a [PeriodicWave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PeriodicWave) from these sample values, which can be done by using [AudioContext.createPeriodicWave()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createPeriodicWave).

However, this method accepts the following arguments instead of sampled values:

- **real**: An array of cosine terms (traditionally the A terms).
- **imag**: An array of sine terms (traditionally the B terms).

I'm not quite sure what these values mean in regard to an array of sampled values. **How can I make a conversion from sampled values to cosine terms and sine terms?**

*Edit: the curve that is sampled is not necessarily a sine or cosine wave. It can take any arbitrary shape.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just want to take a waveform, then just use an AudioBufferSource and loop it (as an AudioBuffer).

PeriodicWaves are something different - they're a way of controlling the waveform of the Oscillator harmonically, by changing the relative coefficients of each harmonic.  If you created a PeriodicWave with only the value "1" in the second slot of the "imag" array, you would get a sine wave.  Likewise, you can create square, triangle, or sawtooth waves by controlling the higher harmonics - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-sinusoidal_waveform.  These waves can end up being pretty rich -

If you want to turn it into a PeriodicWave, you need to turn it into the set of relative harmonic strengths used by PeriodicWave, using an FFT algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform is a decent introduction).  There are libraries on the net to do this, like DSP.js (https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/).

(This used to be called Wavetable, but that was confusing too.  Maybe it should have been renamed HarmonicWaveTable?)

Comment: I get it now, so it's an array of definitions for an array of simple waves, each subsequently one or more octaves higher (having double or more the frequency) than the previous.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure the time-domain waveform you have is periodic, then you can just take the Fourier transform of the waveform to get the Fourier coefficients.  The real and imaginary parts of the transform can be passed as the `real` and `imag` parameters to `createPeriodicWave`.

But if you already have the waveform, just save it in an `AudioBuffer`, assign it to an `AudioBufferSourceNode`, set `loop` to `true`, and use that as your audio source instead of an `OscillatorNode` with a custom `PeriodicWave`.